# How can I navigate between cells in a JSF datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'd like to know how I can use javascript to navigate between the cells in a Java Server Faces (h:dataTable) or Primefaces (p:datatable) datatable.

Here's an example of the navigation I'm talking about: [[Jquery Sample]](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/excel).

Comment: Your question is not very readable. Please add more details about what you are trying to accomplish and give screenshots is possible.

Comment: I add link for show this . second table and jquery sample